# How to get audio track assignment in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

Is there a way to get the audio track assignment in `ffmpeg`? For example, if you are in QuickTime, you can view info (Command - I), and see the track assignment. It looks something like this:

```
Apple ProRes 422 (HQ), 1,920 x 1,080
Linear PCM, 24 bit little-endian signed integer, 48000 Hz, **Left**
Linear PCM, 24 bit little-endian signed integer, 48000 Hz, **Right**
Linear PCM, 24 bit little-endian signed integer, 48000 Hz, **Center**
Linear PCM, 24 bit little-endian signed integer, 48000 Hz, **LFE Screen**
etc...
```

When I do `$ ffmpeg -i`, it does not show the track assignments --

```
Stream #0:12(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32, 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2010-09-16 02:23:49
  handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:13(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32, 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2010-09-16 02:23:49
  handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:14(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32, 1152 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2010-09-16 02:23:49
  handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:15(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32, 2304 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2010-09-16 02:23:49
  handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream #0:16(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32, 2304 kb/s
```

Is there a way to get the track assignments in ffmpeg or another program?

Answer (score 0):

`$ffmpeg -i` outputs channel information in audio stream description. For example:

```
Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 ([0] [0][0] / 0x2000), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), s16, 448 kb/s
```

where:
5.1(side) - front center, left and right, side left and right, and LFE channels. 
s16 - 16-bit signed integer samples.

See samplefmt.h and audioconvert.h from ffmpeg source for other multi-channel and sample formats and their string representations.

Comment: I have updated my question to show what I am currently getting. It does not show "side" in my output.

Comment: It shows several audio streams that are 1 channels (mono?) and stereo, where layout is obvious. If you see more in QuickTime, I guess ffmpeg does not recognize it.